# Why is 'DIRS': ['templates'] also works?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-2.0

To be able to find the template file in django, everybody said you should amend the settings.py like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [{
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
}]
```

but I found that this also works:

```
TEMPLATES = [{
    'DIRS': ['templates'],
}]
```

My question is what is the difference between them. Why does no one recommend `'DIRS': ['templates']`?

Answer (score 1):

If you pass a relative path like `'templates'` to the `DIRS` setting, it will be interpreted as relative to the current directory, e.g. the directory you're in when running `./manage.py runserver`.

If you try to run the server from a different directory, then this path will probably point to a non-existing directory and your page won't render.

If you pass an absolute path instead, then your app will work properly regardless of the working directory.

---

Now, How to get the absolute path? Take the absolute path of the project (`BASE_DIR`) and add `templates` at the end - this is what `os.path.join` does for you.